# While sleeping in a sukkah, are you exempt from prayer?

Tags: halacha, sleep, sukkah, hefsek-interruption, petur-exemption

Someone engrossed in one mitzvah is sometimes [exempt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osek_b%27mitzvah_patur_min_hamitzvah) from certain other mitzvot.

So, I wonder, based on a [question](http://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/comments/16jz2u/halacha_hypo_tzitzis_on_a_blanket/c7wshpn) from Reddit user GutsAndGlory2:

While engaged in the mitzvah of sleeping in a sukkah, are you exempt from saying the morning Shemoneh Esrei?

Comment: So what, Chazal only composed a prayer service for Sukkot in case it rained?

Comment: @DoubleAA, maybe they composed it for early risers.

Comment: @msh210 Ah I hadn't considered your diyuk. I was assuming being in the sukkah is the same kiyum (תשבו כעין תדורו).

Comment: @DoubleAA, when one's awake presumably he'd not be exempt, as one can pray in the _suka_. But the question was about someone sleeping.

Comment: I've prayed in my sleep before, but I was instructed to repeat it as it didn't count.

Comment: Continuing in what I see as the tongue-in-cheek tone of the question: He should dwell in the sukkah as he dwells in his house.  If at home he sleeps through shacharit, he should do the same in the sukkah.

Answer (score 4):

I recall hearing of an halachic opinion (not necessarily to be relied upon!) that anyone sleeping is exempt from *mitzvos* since he is incapacitated and thus *anus*. I can't cite that view at the moment, but according to it, yes, someone sleeping in a *suka* is exempt from *shacharis*.

Comment: As someone sleeping not in the *sukkah* as well :)

Comment: +1. msh210, see pages 12-17 of ["Sleep in Halacha"](http://download.yutorah.org/2009/1109/735393.pdf) by Rabbi Aryeh Lebowitz of Yeshiva University. R' Lebowitz cites R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach's discussion (_Halichos Shlomo_, Tefillah, Miluim #12) about whether or not sleeping people are exempt from _mitzvos_. Dear all: How do most authorities rule regarding this matter?